shift slur/tie not working in Gregorian Chant musixgre library
It is needed to code the "Canticum Zachariae" Gregorian Chant using Musixtex with musixgre library, but the shift slur is not working (it is needed shift left slur). The basic code is as follow:
\documentclass[%
border={2pt 7pt 2pt -7pt},% left bottom right top
%border=8pt
varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{scalerel}%Escalar símbolos
\usepackage{musixtex}
\input musixlyr
\input musixlit
\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
\usepackage{amsmath}%
\usepackage{amssymb}% %$\shortmid$ and $\mid$
\usepackage{xcolor}
\xdefinecolor{red-undar}{RGB}{179,35,79}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lilyglyphs}
\begin{document}
\begin{music}
\hsize=\linewidth%
\resetlyrics
\setlyrics{Letras}{Be-ne-{\hspace{1.5cm}-dic-tus Dó-mi-nus} De-us Is-ra-el: qu-ia {\hspace{1.0cm}visitávit, et fecit redemptiónem} ple-bis su-\ae: Et e-{\hspace{0.6cm}réxit cornu salútis nobis: in domo} Da-vid púe-ri-sui. Si-cut {\hspace{0.3cm}locútus est per os sanctorum, qui a s{\ae}culo sunt, prophe}-tá-rum ei-us: Sa-lú-{\hspace{0.7cm}tem ex inimicis nostris, et de manu ómnium} qui o-dér-unt nos:}%
\setsongraise{1}{0.15cm}
\font\A=phvb8t at 6pt% added for letter type.
\font\B=phvb8t at 13pt% added for letter type.
%\parindent0mm
%\sepbarrules
\instrumentnumber{1}
\nobarnumbers
\setlines14
\setclef1{4000}
\setstaffs11
\setaltoclefsymbol1\gregorianCclef
\newcommand{\ustt}[1]{\raisebox{0.2\Interligne}{\kern-1.4pt \ust {#1}\kern1.4pt}}% normal size \ust centered and put higher for notes on a line
%
\newcommand{\usttt}[1]{\zcharnote {#1}{\A\textbf\medtype \kern0.3pt\raisebox{0.1\Interligne}-\kern0.3pt}}% shorter \ust
%
\newcommand{\btt}[1]{\zcharnote {#1}{\A\textbf{\kern1.16pt \raisebox{-0.9\Interligne}{\lilyGlyph{rests.M1neomensural}}\kern-1.16pt}}}% vertical bar below center of note head (original distance) 
\newcommand{\ptt}[1]{\kern-4pt\pt {#1}\kern4pt}% point closer to note head (original distance is defined for larger \nq)
%
%\newcommand{\caeg}{\zcharnote{5}{\hbsk\begin{tikzpicture}%Barra Vertical
%\draw[line width=0.5pt,draw=black] (0.35,-0.295) -- ++(0,0.15); %
%\end{tikzpicture}}}% works, but quite complicated if there is an existing symbol in amssymb
%
\newcommand{\caeg}{\charnote{b}{\kern-4.1pt$\A\textbf\shortmid$\kern4.1pt}\hbsk}% see differences in spacing
%
\newcommand{\dsbr}{\notes\zcharnote M{\kern-1.1pt$\A\textbf\mid\hspace{-0.125cm}\mid$\kern1.1pt}\hbsk\en}% see differences in spacing
%
\newcommand{\sbr}{\notes\zcharnote M{\kern-1.1pt$\A\textbf\mid$\kern1.1pt}\hbsk\en}% see differences in spacing
%
\newcommand{\sbre}{\zcharnote O{\kern-1.6pt$\A\textbf\mid$}}% see differences in spacing
%
\startpiece%
\A\assignlyrics{1}{Letras}%
\addspace{0.5\afterruleskip}%
\notes\diapunc{M}\isluru0N\diapunc{N}\hbsk\tslur0{a}\nolyr\diapunc{a}\lyr\Hpause{a}{2}\sk\sk\sk\diapunc{_b}\diapunc{a}\diapunc{N}\diapunc{a}\diapunc{a}\en%
\zalaligne%
\notes\hbsk\diapunc{M}\isluru0N\diapunc{N}\hbsk\tslur0{a}\nolyr\diapunc{a}\lyr\Hpause{a}{2}\sk\sk\sk\diapunc{_b}\diapunc{a}\diapunc{N}\diapunc{a}\en%
\zalaligne%
\notes\diapunc{M}\isluru0N\diapunc{N}\hbsk\tslur0{a}\nolyr\diapunc{a}\lyr\Hpause{a}{2}\sk\sk\sk\diapunc{_b}\diapunc{a}\diapunc{N}\diapunc{a}\diapunc{a}\en%
\zalaligne%
\notes\diapunc{M}\isluru0N\diapunc{N}\hbsk\tslur0{a}\nolyr\diapunc{a}\lyr\Hpause{a}{5}\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\diapunc{_b}\diapunc{a}\diapunc{N}\diapunc{a}\en%
\zalaligne%
\notes\diapunc{M}\isluru0N\diapunc{N}\hbsk\tslur0{a}\nolyr\diapunc{a}\lyr\Hpause{a}{4}\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\diapunc{_b}\diapunc{a}\diapunc{N}\diapunc{a}\diapunc{a}\en%
%\zalaligne%
\zstoppiece
%\nolyr%
%\lyricsoff%
\end{music}
\end{document}

The current output is as follow:

When try to implement the command: ilsluru, the slur dissapears... The basic code is as follow:
\documentclass[%
border={2pt 7pt 2pt -7pt},% left bottom right top
%border=8pt
varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{scalerel}%Escalar símbolos
\usepackage{musixtex}
\input musixlyr%
\input musixlit%
\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
\input musixps%
\usepackage{amsmath}%
\usepackage{amssymb}% %$\shortmid$ and $\mid$
\usepackage{xcolor}
\xdefinecolor{red-undar}{RGB}{179,35,79}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lilyglyphs}
\begin{document}
\begin{music}
\hsize=\linewidth%
\resetlyrics
\setlyrics{Letras}{Be-ne-{\hspace{1.5cm}-dic-tus Dó-mi-nus} De-us Is-ra-el: {\hspace{4.5cm}quia visitávit, et fecit redemptiónem} ple-bis su-{\ae}: Et er-{{\hspace{2.5cm}-éxit  cornu  sal}}-{\'u}-tis no-bis: {{\hspace{3.5cm}in domo David}} pú-e-ri-sui. Si-cut {{\hspace{3.1cm}locútus est per}} os san-ctó-rum, {{\hspace{4.5cm}qui a s{\ae}culo sunt, prophe}}-t{\'a}-rum ei-us: Sa-l{\'u}-{{\hspace{0.7cm}tem ex inimicis nostris, et de manu ómnium}} qui o-dér-unt nos:}%
\setsongraise{1}{0.15cm}
\font\A=phvb8t at 6pt% added for letter type.
\font\B=phvb8t at 13pt% added for letter type.
\instrumentnumber{1}
\nobarnumbers
\setlines14
\setclef1{4000}
\setstaffs11
\setaltoclefsymbol1\gregorianCclef
\newcommand{\ustt}[1]{\raisebox{0.2\Interligne}{\kern-1.4pt \ust {#1}\kern1.4pt}}% normal size \ust centered and put higher for notes on a line
%
\newcommand{\usttt}[1]{\zcharnote {#1}{\A\textbf\medtype \kern0.3pt\raisebox{0.1\Interligne}-\kern0.3pt}}% shorter \ust
%
\newcommand{\btt}[1]{\zcharnote {#1}{\A\textbf{\kern1.16pt \raisebox{-0.9\Interligne}{\lilyGlyph{rests.M1neomensural}}\kern-1.16pt}}}% vertical bar below center of note head (original distance) 
\newcommand{\ptt}[1]{\kern-4pt\pt {#1}\kern4pt}% point closer to note head (original distance is defined for larger \nq)
%
%\newcommand{\caeg}{\zcharnote{5}{\hbsk\begin{tikzpicture}%Barra Vertical
%\draw[line width=0.5pt,draw=black] (0.35,-0.295) -- ++(0,0.15); %
%\end{tikzpicture}}}% works, but quite complicated if there is an existing symbol in amssymb
%
\newcommand{\caeg}{\charnote{b}{\kern-4.1pt$\A\textbf\shortmid$\kern4.1pt}\hbsk}% see differences in spacing
%
\newcommand{\dsbr}{\notes\zcharnote M{\kern-1.1pt$\A\textbf\mid\hspace{-0.125cm}\mid$\kern1.1pt}\hbsk\en}% see differences in spacing
%
\newcommand{\sbr}{\notes\zcharnote M{\kern-1.1pt$\A\textbf\mid$\kern1.1pt}\hbsk\en}% see differences in spacing
%
\newcommand{\sbre}{\zcharnote O{\kern-1.6pt$\A\textbf\mid$}}% see differences in spacing
%
\startpiece%
\A\assignlyrics{1}{Letras}%
\addspace{0.5\afterruleskip}%
\notes\diapunc{M}\ilsluru1{N}\diapunc{N}\hbsk\tlslur1{a}\nolyr\diapunc{a}\lyr\Hpause{a}{2}\sk\sk\sk\diapunc{_b}\diapunc{a}\diapunc{N}\diapunc{a}\diapunc{a}\en%
\zalaligne%
\notes\lyr\Hpause{a}{5}\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\diapunc{N}\diapunc{M}\isluru0N\diapunc{N}\hbsk\tslur0{a}\nolyr\diapunc{a}\isluru0N\diapunc{N}\hbsk\tslur0{M}\nolyr\diapunc{M}\en%
\zalaligne%
\notes\diapunc{M}\isluru0N\diapunc{N}\hbsk\tslur0{a}\nolyr\diapunc{a}\lyr\Hpause{a}{4}\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\diapunc{_b}\diapunc{a}\diapunc{N}\diapunc{a}\en%
\zalaligne%
\notes\lyr\Hpause{a}{5}\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\diapunc{N}\diapunc{M}\isluru0N\diapunc{N}\hbsk\tslur0{a}\nolyr\diapunc{a}\isluru0N\diapunc{N}\hbsk\tslur0{M}\nolyr\diapunc{M}\en%
\zalaligne%
\notes\diapunc{M}\isluru0N\diapunc{N}\hbsk\tslur0{a}\nolyr\diapunc{a}\lyr\Hpause{a}{5}\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\diapunc{_b}\diapunc{a}\diapunc{N}\diapunc{a}\en%
\zalaligne%
\notes\lyr\Hpause{a}{7}\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\diapunc{N}\diapunc{M}\isluru0N\diapunc{N}\hbsk\tslur0{a}\nolyr\diapunc{a}\isluru0N\diapunc{N}\hbsk\tslur0{M}\nolyr\diapunc{M}\en%
\zstoppiece%
%\nolyr%
%\lyricsoff%
\end{music}
\end{document}

The output is as follow:


Please tidy up your code: there are melismas in the music, or use "_" in the text, in stead of indicating where there has to be placed text and where not. Hard lyrics should be left aligned (there is a command '\lsong').   Probably the "problem" is caused by the dimension of the note head, which is smaller than an nq, so you should shift either the note head to the right or the end of the slur to the left. For this, there are standard commands in the musixps.tex input (see Chapter 11 of musixdoc.pdf). If those do not please you, first try to puzzle for a work around yourself.

Have you read Chapter 11? It tells you: "Two minor inconveniences with type K Postscript slurs are that (1) they won’t appear in many dvi previewers, and (2) they won’t appear in PDF files generated with pdftex or dvipdfm. The former limitation can be circumvented by using a Postscript viewer such as GSview. The latter simply requires that you create an intermediate Postscript file with dvips, then make the PDF with any of the software mentioned above." In TeXShop you can do this in one step in "preferences".

Solved (thanks Peters):
\documentclass[%
border={2pt 7pt 2pt -7pt},% left bottom right top
%border=8pt
varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{scalerel}%Escalar símbolos
\usepackage{musixtex}
\input musixlyr%
\input musixlit%
\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
\input musixps%
\usepackage{amsmath}%
\usepackage{amssymb}% %$\shortmid$ and $\mid$
\usepackage{xcolor}
\xdefinecolor{red-undar}{RGB}{179,35,79}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
%\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lilyglyphs}
\begin{document}
\begin{music}
\hsize=\linewidth%
\resetlyrics
\setlyrics{Letras}{Be-ne-{\hspace{1.5cm}-dic-tus D\'o-mi-nus} De-us Is-ra-el: {\hspace{4.5cm}quia visitávit, et fecit redemptiónem} ple-bis su-{\ae}: Et er-{{\hspace{2.3cm}-éxit  cornu  sal}}-{\'u}-tis no-bis: {{\hspace{4.1cm}in domo David}} pú-e-ri-sui. Si-cut {{\hspace{2.1cm}locútus est per}} os san-ctó-rum, {{\hspace{5.5cm}qui a s{\ae}culo sunt, prophe}}-t{\'a}-rum ei-us: Sa-l{\'u}-{{\hspace{0.7cm}tem ex inimicis nostris, et de manu ómnium}} qui o-dér-unt nos:}%
\setsongraise{1}{0.15cm}
\font\A=phvb8t at 6pt% added for letter type.
\font\B=phvb8t at 13pt% added for letter type.
\instrumentnumber{1}
\nobarnumbers
\setlines14
\setclef1{4000}
\setstaffs11
\setaltoclefsymbol1\gregorianCclef
\newcommand{\ustt}[1]{\raisebox{0.2\Interligne}{\kern-1.4pt \ust {#1}\kern1.4pt}}% normal size \ust centered and put higher for notes on a line
%
\newcommand{\usttt}[1]{\zcharnote {#1}{\A\textbf\medtype \kern0.3pt\raisebox{0.1\Interligne}-\kern0.3pt}}% shorter \ust
%
\newcommand{\btt}[1]{\zcharnote {#1}{\A\textbf{\kern1.16pt \raisebox{-0.9\Interligne}{\lilyGlyph{rests.M1neomensural}}\kern-1.16pt}}}% vertical bar below center of note head (original distance) 
\newcommand{\ptt}[1]{\kern-4pt\pt {#1}\kern4pt}% point closer to note head (original distance is defined for larger \nq)
%
%\newcommand{\caeg}{\zcharnote{5}{\hbsk\begin{tikzpicture}%Barra Vertical
%\draw[line width=0.5pt,draw=black] (0.35,-0.295) -- ++(0,0.15); %
%\end{tikzpicture}}}% works, but quite complicated if there is an existing symbol in amssymb
%
\newcommand{\caeg}{\charnote{b}{\kern-4.1pt$\A\textbf\shortmid$\kern4.1pt}\hbsk}% see differences in spacing
%
\newcommand{\dsbr}{\notes\zcharnote M{\kern-1.1pt$\A\textbf\mid\hspace{-0.125cm}\mid$\kern1.1pt}\hbsk\en}% see differences in spacing
%
\newcommand{\sbr}{\notes\zcharnote M{\kern-1.1pt$\A\textbf\mid$\kern1.1pt}\hbsk\en}% see differences in spacing
%
\newcommand{\sbre}{\zcharnote O{\kern-1.6pt$\A\textbf\mid$}}% see differences in spacing
%
\startpiece%
\A\assignlyrics{1}{Letras}%
\addspace{0.5\afterruleskip}%
\notes\diapunc{M}\ilsluru1{N}\diapunc{N}\hbsk\tlslur1{a}\nolyr\diapunc{a}\lyr\Hpause{a}{2}\sk\sk\sk\diapunc{_b}\diapunc{a}\diapunc{N}\diapunc{a}\diapunc{a}\en%
\zalaligne%
\notes\lyr\Hpause{a}{5}\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\diapunc{N}\diapunc{M}\ilsluru0N\diapunc{N}\hbsk\tlslur0{a}\nolyr\diapunc{a}\ilsluru0N\diapunc{N}\hbsk\tlslur0{M}\nolyr\diapunc{M}\en%
\zalaligne%
\notes\diapunc{M}\isluru0N\diapunc{N}\hbsk\tslur0{a}\nolyr\diapunc{a}\lyr\Hpause{a}{4}\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\diapunc{_b}\diapunc{a}\diapunc{N}\diapunc{a}\en%
\zalaligne%
\notes\lyr\Hpause{a}{5}\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\diapunc{N}\diapunc{M}\ilsluru0N\diapunc{N}\hbsk\tlslur0{a}\nolyr\diapunc{a}\ilsluru0N\diapunc{N}\hbsk\tlslur0{M}\nolyr\diapunc{M}\en%
\zalaligne%
\notes\diapunc{M}\ilsluru0N\diapunc{N}\hbsk\tlslur0{a}\nolyr\diapunc{a}\lyr\Hpause{a}{5}\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\diapunc{_b}\diapunc{a}\diapunc{N}\diapunc{a}\en%
\zalaligne%
\notes\lyr\Hpause{a}{7}\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\diapunc{N}\diapunc{M}\ilsluru0N\diapunc{N}\hbsk\tlslur0{a}\nolyr\diapunc{a}\ilsluru0N\diapunc{N}\hbsk\tlslur0{M}\nolyr\diapunc{M}\en%
\zstoppiece%
%\nolyr%
%\lyricsoff%
\end{music}
\end{document}

If you use TexStudio, you need to adjust it:
user1:musixps
txs:///dvi-ps-pdf-chain | musixflx % | txs:///dvi-ps-pdf-chain
The solved output is as follow:

